# Hide and show div with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, html, show-hide

Well, this is the first time i'm using jquery mobile.
I'm trying to make a single page mobile app and i have two divs like follows:

```
<div data-role="page" id="divStart">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a id='btnShowSignUp' data-role="button" href='#' onclick="ShowSignUp();">Sign Up</a>
            <a id='btnShowSignUp' data-role="button" href='#' onclick="ShowLogin();">Login</a>
        </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="divSignUp" style='display: none'>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form id='formSignUp' method='POST'>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input name="name" id="name" type="text">
                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    <input name="email" id="email" type="text">
                    <label for="pass">Pass</label>
                    <input name="pass" id="pass" type="password">
                </div>
                <a data-role="button" href="#" onclick='SignUp();'>Save</a>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

When i click the button 'btnShowSignUp', i call the function:

```
function ShowSignUp(){
    $('#divStart').hide();
    $('#divSignUp').show();
}
```

My problem: when i click the button, the 'divStart' disappear and the 'divSignUp' shows up, but it misses some of its jquery mobile attributes. Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't following JQM's navigation API. The JQM framework manages the showing and hiding of your various "pages", along with applying any transition between them:

```
 function ShowSignUp(){
   $.mobile.changePage( "#divStart" );
 }
```

With a fancy transition:

```
 $.mobile.changePage( "#divStart", { transition: "pop" });
```

If you try doing JQM's job for it, you're likely going to end up with unanticipated results.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/